# CSS reach nested div

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is this how i write to reach the div phone in this code with nested divs?

**CSS**

```
#pagewrap #pagemain .content .colrow .container .col548 #contactInfoArea #phone
{

}
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- Start: Pagewrap -->
<div id="pagewrap">
<div id="header">
    <div class="headerWrapper">
        <div id="headerTopItems"> <a class="mainLink" href="../Telge-Energi/Webbkarta/">Webbkarta</a> <a href="#" class="login closed">Min Sida</a>
            <div id="loginBoxWrapper">
                <div id="loginBoxButtonWrapper">
                    <div class="rounded buttonWrapper"></div>
                    <div id="topLoginButton">
                        <div class="rounded topLeft"></div>
                        <div class="rounded topRight"></div>
                        <a href="#" class="login open">Logga in</a> </div>
                    <div id="loginButtonShadow">
                        <div class="rounded topRight"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="loginBox">
                    <div class="rounded topLeft"></div>
                    <div class="rounded bottomLeft"></div>
                    <div class="rounded bottomRight"></div>
                    <div class="formWrapper"> </div>
                </div>
                <div id="loginBoxShadow">
                    <div class="rounded bottomLeft"></div>
                    <div class="rounded bottomRight"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='searchForm png'> 

                <!--<div class="top-search png">-->

                <div id="ctl00_PageHeadRegion_ctl00_ctl00_QuickSearch1_Panel1" class="QuickSearchArea" onKeyPress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_PageHeadRegion_ctl00_ctl00_QuickSearch1_SearchButton')"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="ctl00_TopSelectionPanel">
            <div id="topSelection"> 
                <!--<div class="menu">-->
                <div class='roundedtopLeft'></div>
                <ul>
                </ul>
                <div class='rounded topRight'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Only visible for TE-->

    <div id="topMenu">
        <div class='rounded topLeft'></div>
        <div class='rounded topRight'></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Start: Pagemain -->
<div id="pagemain">
    <div class="content"> 

        <!-- Visible for others then TE-->

        <div class="colrow"> 

            <!--Start: Left Manu -->

            <div id="leftmenu">
                <div id="ctl00_FullContentRegion_MainRegion_SubMenu_EmptyMenuPanel"> </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Start: Container -->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="verticalDivider left"></div>

                <!--Start: Main Area -->

                <div class="col548">
                    <div id="topnav">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="active"><a href="." class="first">Namn Rubrik</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <img id="ctl00_FullContentRegion_MainRegion_MainContentRegion_MainBodyRegion_Image" src="../Global/Bilder/contact.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" /> <span>Namn Rubrik</span> <span>Utvecklare</span><br />
                    <div id="contactInfoArea"> **
                        <div id="phone">**
                            071-234567 </div>
                        <div id="mobile"> <span>071-234567</span> </div>
                        <div id="email"> <a href="mailto:namn@foretag.se"><span>namn@foretag.se</span></a> </div>
                    </div>
                    <span>Portals &amp; Web</span><br />
                    <span id="ctl00_FullContentRegion_MainRegion_MainContentRegion_MainBodyRegion_XForm1_PostedMessage" class="thankyoumessage"></span>
                    <div id="ctl00_FullContentRegion_MainRegion_MainContentRegion_MainBodyRegion_XForm1_FormPanel" class="xForm"> </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="contentfooter">
                        <p><a href="javascript:window.print();" class="print">Skriv ut</a></p>
                        <p><a href="#" class="share">Tipsa en vän</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="verticalDivider right"></div>
                <div class="col172"> 

                    <!-- Start: Slidingdrawer --> 

                    <!-- Start: Spot module --> 

                    <span id="ctl00_FullContentRegion_MainRegion_MainContentRegion_SecondaryBodyRegion_ErrorMessage" class="errorMessage" style="font-size:Small;"></span> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="ctl00_PageFooterPanel"> 

    <!-- Start: Pagefooter -->
    <div id="pagefooter"> 

        <!-- Start: Contentfooter -->

        <div class="content">
            <div> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- page_completed --> 

<script src="../WebResource.axd?d=U8UcbPv0K0IV1GYpkK2BgA2&amp;t=634202716197779592" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
EPi.SetupPropertyObjects = function()
{
    EPi.RegisterPropertyObject(window, "EPiObject", {EPiOnPageEditControl:"OnPageEditControl"});
}
//]]>
</script>
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: I think you could read up on CSS, that would help you alot I think :-)

Comment: @Andy, check your question after you post it (*or check the preview while you type it*) to make sure it is displayed as you wanted and edit it, if something is amiss, so that people can understand what is being asked..

Comment: @Andy: If you have such a HTML structure, it's a good chance your are doing something wrong, and are suffering of "divitis".

Comment: W3schools has a nice introduction into CSS: http://w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp

Comment: It's not me that wrote the code. I'm just trying to fix it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For those of us who are not experts, this is a very reasonable question. I think the experts in stack need to be a little more compassionate with those of us who are still learning what may seem obvious to others.  I don't think this question should have been closed.  It asked a real question and obviously received a valuable answer.

Comment: This is an old question, but I have to say that several of the comments are pretty rude.  Andy asked a reasonable question, if a beginners question, and several people jumped down his throat instead of saying something useful (or nothing at all).  Please don't be under the impression that such comments "make the internet better" as J Atwood has always said SO is all about.

Answer (score 11):

An id is unique in the page, so all you need is:

```
#phone {
}
```

If you use the style sheet for several pages, and the id might be used for something else on some other page, you can for example specify that it should only apply if it is part of the contact info:

```
#contactInfoArea #phone {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You will use `#phone`. IDs are unique and will occur only once in a document.

Comment: Well, there is a small chance, that other documents using the same style sheet have a `#phone` element, which is not inside those other elements and which should not be styled....

Comment: This is true, but the OP was only asking how to select a node with a specific ID.

Answer (score 1):

```
#phone {

}
```

does the trick because (#phone is an ID and ID's are unique :-))

Answer (score 0):

Anything wrong with the inline `style` attribute? :p